# Permalinks to chat messages do not scroll to the message properly

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

1. Access the beta chat
2. Try reading this message: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/chats/message/5365
3. Notice how the message is momentarily placed at the top of the screen in yellow
4. Notice how the message is pushed down as question, answer, user links, images, wikipedia links, etc. above it are loaded.
5. The message, hilighted in yellow, moves down to another <s>castle</s> screenful

This is most noticeable when first loading the page, as most of the blocks with "delayed loading" will be cached otherwise. Use Ctrl-F5 to see the problem in full effect.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because we don't know the dimensions of any embedded user images "above" the message.